# Is it possible to limit a user to 1 command every x seconds?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I know there is a command cooldown for separate commands but I'm wondering if you could limit every command at once so no matter what command the person uses it will have a cooldown afterwards before the next command can be used. So if I ran `!test` I cant use `!test1` for another 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, infact I believe the library `discord.py` does provide this functionality as a decorator on your command function - though I can't remember what the function name is off the top of my head

Comment: The answer below will work - though, not optimized for performance. You probably want to use subcommands/groups with the cooldown decorator for performance. The decorators provided by the library are very well understood and benchmarked.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a global cooldown instance

```py
global_cooldown = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 5.0, commands.BucketType.user) # Feel free to change it
```

And then add a check, if you want a global cooldown for **all** commands:

```py
@bot.check
async def cooldown_check(ctx):
    bucket = global_cooldown.get_bucket(ctx.message)
    retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    if retry_after:
        raise commands.CommandOnCooldown(bucket, retry_after)
    return True
```

All commands will have a shared cooldown.

If you want a decorator for a few commands with a shared cooldown

```py
def shared_cooldown():
    def predicate(ctx):
        bucket = global_cooldown.get_bucket(ctx.message)
        retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
        if retry_after:
            raise commands.CommandOnCooldown(bucket, retry_after)
        return True
    return commands.check(predicate)

@shared_cooldown()
async def foo(ctx):
    ...

@shared_cooldown()
async def baz(ctx):
    ...
```

`foo` and `baz` will have a shared cooldown.